# The inner loop only runs once

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am curious as though, why when I use an array in for-loop in the given manner below, the inner loop only runs once.
Thank you for your reply.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;



int main(){
    
    int a[2]={0};
    a[0]=5;
    for(a[0];a[0]<10;a[0]+=1){
        for(a[1];a[1]<10;a[1]+=1){
            cout<<a[0]<<" "<<a[1]<<endl;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code you'll figure it out. If you still have a question, ask that specific question. _"Why is my code doing this"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)
Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: What's the value of `a[1]`?

Comment: `a[1]` is never reset to zero in the outer loop, that's why you see combinations for `a[0] == 5` only.

Comment: I was confused at what you mean but here is the code online: [https://ideone.com/gzxpvN](https://ideone.com/gzxpvN) You probably should have added your output to the question.

Comment: Note: `a[0];`, and `a[1];` in for loop initialization step is a noop.

Answer (score 2):

You are never resetting a[1], so once it hits 10 the first time through the inner loop, it will never execute again. Modify to `for(a[1]=0;a[1]<10;a[1]+=1){`